# PHP email with attached file always 41B and not working:

Tags: php, email, attachment

Whenever i send an email with attachment the file is 41B and it is not working. How to fix it? I've tried with jpeg and zip and all was the same. The file is with its name and extension but it is 41B and cannot open it.

This is my code:

```
if($_POST){
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
    if(!empty($_POST['author']) && preg_match($email_exp,($_POST['email']))){
        $mail_to = "example@example.com";
        $from_mail = $_POST['email'];
        $from_name = $_POST['author'];
        $reply_to = "reply@example.com";
        $subject = "Subject";
        $boundary = md5(uniqid(time()));
        $message = "<html><head></head><body>Author: ".$_POST['author']."<br >E-mail: ".$_POST['email']."</body></html>";

        //Set e-mail headers
        $headers = "From: ".$from_name."<".$from_mail.">\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$reply_to."\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\nboundary=\"".$boundary."\"\r\n";
        $headers .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
        $headers .= "--".$boundary."\r\n";

        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
        $headers .= "$message\r\n";
        $headers .= "--".$boundary."\r\n";

        if(!empty($_FILES['picture1']['name']) || !empty($_FILES['picture2']['name']) || !empty($_FILES['picture3']['name']) || !empty($_FILES['picture4']['name']) || !empty($_FILES['picture5']['name'])){
            $file = array($_FILES['picture1']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['picture1']['name'], $_FILES['picture1']['size'],$_FILES['picture2']['tmp_name'], 
            $_FILES['picture2']['name'],$_FILES['picture2']['size'], $_FILES['picture3']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['picture3']['name'], $_FILES['picture3']['size'], 
            $_FILES['picture4']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['picture4']['name'], $_FILES['picture4']['size'], $_FILES['picture5']['tmp_name'], 
            $_FILES['picture5']['name'], $_FILES['picture5']['size']);
            for($i=0;$i<15;$i+=3){
                if(!empty($file[$i])){
                    $headers .= "Content-Type: application/xml;\r\n name=\"".$file[$i+1]."\"\r\n";
                    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
                    $headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment;\r\n filename=\"".$file[$i+1]."\"\r\n";
                    $cnt = $file[$i].$file[$i+2];
                    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($cnt));
                    $headers .= "\r\n".$content."\r\n";
                    $headers .= "--".$boundary."--\r\n";
                    echo $i;
                }
            }
        }
        if(mail($mail_to, $subject, "", $headers)){
            echo 'MAIL SENT';
        }else {
            echo 'MAIL FAILED';
        }

    }else{
        echo "The fields!";
    }
}
```

Comment: You should try https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer it is probably the best mail lib for php. You could face great number of problems with mail and PHPMailer solves almost all of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your code:

---

```
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
```

This regexp excludes a lot of valid email addresses, for example anything from the `.museum` domain, or the `local-part` in addresses such as `^_^@domain.example` or `"^stack\ exchange$"@domain.example`.

---

```
$from_mail = $_POST['email'];
$from_name = $_POST['author'];
/* ... */
$headers = "From: ".$from_name."<".$from_mail.">\r\n";
```

You should ensure that there are no control characters (such as `\r\n`) in those variables. As it is, a malicious user can comfortably inject their own email headers (`Bcc:` or similar).

---

```
$message = "<html><head></head><body>Author: ".$_POST['author']."<br >E-mail: ".$_POST['email']."</body></html>";
```

You should run those `$_POST` variables through [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to prevent malicious users from injecting arbitrary scripts or other elements of their choice.

---

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\nboundary=\"".$boundary."\"\r\n";
```

This is wrong. You cannot put the `boundary` part on its own line. If you want to break a long header line, you have to use [*Folding White Space*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.2.2), i.e. a `CR LF SP` or `CR LF HTAB` sequence (`"\r\n "` or `"\r\n\t"`).

---

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\nboundary=\"".$boundary."\"\r\n";
$headers .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
```

The first line above is the end of the headers. The second line is the start of the message body. There must be a double `"\r\n"` between them. Semantically, everything from the second line should be passed through the third (`$message`) argument to `mail()`. The `mail()` funcion will do some trimming of the headers which may or may not interfere with your message bodies.

---

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: application/xml;\r\n name=\"".$file[$i+1]."\"\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment;\r\n filename=\"".$file[$i+1]."\"\r\n";
```

You may want to ensure that there are no double quotes or control characters in the file names.

---

```
$cnt = $file[$i].$file[$i+2];
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($cnt));
```

As you have noted yourself, you should use `$cnt = file_get_contents($file[$i])`. I mention it here for the sake of completeness.

---

```
$headers .= "\r\n".$content."\r\n";
$headers .= "--".$boundary."--\r\n";
```

This is wrong. The `"\r\n--" ... "--"` is a *close-delimiter*. You should use a *dash-boundary* between each file part, and the *close-delimiter* after the last part. See the syntax section below. Eg.

```
$headers .= "$message\r\n";
/*$headers .= "--".$boundary."\r\n";*/  /* <--- */

if (!empty /* ... */) {
    $file = /* ... */;

    for($i=0;$i<15;$i+=3){
        if(!empty($file[$i])){
/* ---> */  $headers .= "\r\n--$boundary\r\n";</b>
            $headers .= "Content-Type: application/xml;\r\n name=\"".$file[$i+1]."\"\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment;\r\n filename=\"".$file[$i+1]."\"\r\n";
            $cnt = file_get_contents ($file[$i]);
            $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($cnt));
            $headers .= "\r\n".$content;
            echo $i;
        }
    }
}
$headers .= "\r\n--$boundary--\r\n";  /* <--- */
```

---

#### MIME Syntax

This is an excerpt of what the structure of a multi-part message body looks like according to RFC 2046. (BNF syntax, somewhat simplified.)

```
multipart-body := [preamble CRLF]
                  dash-boundary CRLF
                  body-part *encapsulation
                  close-delimiter
                  [CRLF epilogue]

dash-boundary := "--" boundary

body-part := MIME-part-headers [CRLF *OCTET]

encapsulation := delimiter
                 CRLF body-part

delimiter := CRLF dash-boundary

close-delimiter := delimiter "--"
```

#### References

- [RFC 5322 Internet Message Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322)
- [RFC 2045 (MIME) Part One: Format of Internet Message Bodies](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045)
- [RFC 2046 (MIME) Part Two: Media Types](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to replace

```
$cnt = $file[$i].$file[$i+2];
```

with:

```
$cnt = file_get_contents($file[$i]);
```